# Can one find the process of deriving a metric, working backwards using the EFEs?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor

**Disclaimer: I am very new to General Relativity. Excuse the possible inaccurate wording.**

The typical method of deriving the majority of spacetime metrics, as far as I understand, is to assume certain characteristics about the metric in question (e.g. symmetry, metric signature, $T_{ab} = 0$). Then, starting with the spacetime interval, one may find the connection coefficients, Ricci tensor components, and then simplifying would yield the metric (or at least this is true for the Schwarzchild metric).

However, if one were given an arbitrary spacetime metric, without knowing of the process of derivation that was originally used to derive the metric, could the Einstein Field Equations be used to "work backwards" to find the method of derivation?

Say, for instance, if one only had the Schwarzchild metric, and the EFEs, could one find the *process* used to derive the Schwarzchild metric?

Comment: I would think it would be harder to work backward and arrive at the EFEs than just to do the original derivation. I think the best thing to do is just solve them.

Comment: I don't think you can. You can use the mtric to check that it satisfies the EFEs, but how it was derived is harder.

Comment: @MBN might it be possible to use the final metric to make an informed guess of the metric derivation starting from the spacetime interval? There must be certain "patterns" within the final metric that suggest certain steps in deriving it?

Comment: @JS4137 May be, but I doubt that there is a general way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no formulaic method to find how a metric is derived from the Einstein Field Equations. However, there is a somewhat general "method" for doing so, at least for Schwarzschild-like metrics that reduce to flat spacetime.

First, find the coordinates used by the final metric (e.g. Schwarzschild uses polar spherical coordinates), and put the Minkowski line element in that coordinate system. Therefore, we have:

$$
ds^2 = -dt^2 + dr^2 + r^2(d\theta^2 + \sin^2 d \phi^2)
$$

Then, come up with an *ansatz* (guessed form) of the metric, for the case of the Schwarzschild it would be:

$$
ds^2 = -a(r) dt^2 + b(r)dr^2 + r^2(d\theta^2 + \sin^2 d \phi^2)
$$

Finally, the field equations can be used to solve for both $a(r)$ and $b(r)$. Doing so is a lengthy process, but the general steps would be:

1. Using the *ansatz* metric to find the Christoffel symbols
2. Given that $R_{ij} = 0$ (and hence $\partial_k \Gamma^k_{ij} - \partial_j \Gamma^k_{ik} + \Gamma^k_{ij} \Gamma^m_{km} - \Gamma^k_{im} \Gamma^m_{jk} = 0$), substitute in the Christoffel symbols and solve to yield $a(r)$ and $b(r)$
3. Substitute $a(r)$ and $b(r)$ into the original metric

Doing the full calculations is very time-consuming and requires a lot of educated guesswork. However, as far as I can tell, this method does *generally* work.